# Why is minecraft much darker on my Linux side than my Windows side?

Tags: xorg, nvidia, minecraft

I'm using oracle java for both (verified by checking what version of java running process was using). I use an nvidia graphics card. I'm using the latest beta drivers for linux.

This is been an issue across 3 different computers with different types of linux (all debian based...Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, and Mint) and different video cards. It's not terrible, but it is quite noticeable. I remember about 3 or 4 years ago was when I first noticed it.

EDIT:
after taking screenshots and comparing the screenshots in each OS, the game is not any darker or brighter. There must be some sort of color profile going on in linux, because its darker than it should be by a lot. On the moody setting, your view distance is only about 3 to 5 blocks, but unfortunately that aspect isnt captured by screenshot.

Comment: Is your minecraft brightness down?

Comment: @Mew Both are set all the way to "Bright". I can show you screenshots comparing them if it'll help.

Comment: Sure. You might also want to post this to Arqade.

Comment: Sounds like you have a different display gamma on Linux v. Windows. That'd explain why the screenshots are unable to display it. I realize this question is from 2014; is it still relevant?

Comment: @derobert Relevant or not, that comment is the closest thing to an answer this has right now.